# URL alias to access user profile as admin

Tags: users, path-aliases

I realized that users on my site have their path ending in the form "user/number" (for example: user/3) when I check People in the Admin Toolbar and click on their username. I would like to use URL aliasing or some alternative that allows the path end with their username (for example: user/john_smith). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create aliases using the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

There are various tutorials of this module you can [watch](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pathauto).